# Android, Why my html file doesn't show?

Tags: android, html, view

I have stored some of my information in an HTML file and put it in asset folder. However, when I want to show it, web page starts but it says that "Web page not available", while I have stored it in assets folder.

This is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.am_culture); 

        final FrameLayout frame01 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.ch_frame01);
        final WebView wv = new WebView(this);

        frame01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/people.html");
                setContentView(wv);
            }
        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Just a crazy suggestion: try this url: `file://android_asset/people.html` the extra `/` points it to the root of the device, which I do not think the file would be.

Comment: Thanks buddy but it had same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
    WebView mWebView = null;
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb1);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    InputStream is;
    try {
        is = getAssets().open("people.html");
        int size = is.available();
        // Read the entire asset into a local byte buffer.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        // Convert the buffer into a string.
        String strContent = new String(buffer);
        mWebView.loadData(strContent, "text/html", "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I tested it but it didn't work too!!! I saw LogCat and it said that the program jumps to exception because file not found! I have saved this file in root>assets>people.html but I can't understand why it throws exception!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should be your code for retrieving assets' file

```
public String inputStreamToString()
{
    StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    try
    {
        InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("people.html");

        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        for (int n; (n = is.read(b)) != -1;) {
            sBuffer.append(new String(b, 0, n));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        //Log.e("inputstream",e.toString());
    }

    return sBuffer.toString();
}     

public void webview()
{
    WebView wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    String summary = inputStreamToString();
    wb.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
}
```